Which of these mechanical properties is the appropriate one to use in Euler's buckling equation?
Here is a datasheet for some carbon fiber rods. A table of mechanical values from the datasheet is given below.
Which value in this table is the correct one to use for $E$ in Euler's buckling formula $P_{cr} = \frac{\pi^2 E I}{(K L)^2}$,
when measuring compressive axial loads on the rod?



Property
Unit
Value




Tensile Strength Lengthways
MPa
400-500


Tensile Strength Widthways
MPa
18-30


Tensile Modulus Lengthways
GPa
28-40


Tensile Modulus Widthways
GPa
8-12


Flexural Strength Lengthways
MPa
250-400


Flexural Strength Widthways
MPa
80-150


Flexural Modulus Lengthways
GPa
20-30


Flexural Modulus Widthways
GPa
10-15


Compressive Strength Lengthways
MPa
200-320


Compressive Strength Widthways
MPa
60-100


Compressive Modulus Lengthways
GPa
10-20


Compressive Modulus Widthways
GPa
8-20


Short Beam Shear Stress
MPa
30-40


Maximum Service Temperature
°C
80


Barcol Hardness
-
25-45


Density
g/cm³
1.30-1.50



Is it "Compressive modulus lengthways"? or "Tensile modulus lengthways"?

When in doubt, you should use more conservative value, i.e. compressive modulus lengthways. The beam is in compression to which some bending is added when buckling is initiated, so the whole section is still in compression at the start of buckling.
